# Gimp edit all layers simultaneously with brush?

Tags: gimp, layers

I want to edit all layers of the gif simultaneously by applying brush on all layers, I was applying brush on each layer but there are many layers and I can't do this again and again!
Solution for editing multiple layers with the brush tool in Gimp?

Answer (score 0):

No direct solution. My suggestion is to make your change by adding a layer to on which you paint, and then run a script(*) to apply the paint layer to all layers.

(*) see for instance [`ofn-interleave-layers`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/).